# Atom Nuclide connection error - ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: atom-editor

I'm getting an error with Atom Nuclide (1.43.0 x64 running on Windows 10, Nuclide client and server versions both are 287) while trying to connect to a remote project folder (Ubuntu 16.04):

Unable to connect to server
The server successfully started, but we were unable to connect.
Original error message:
 ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'nuclide://XX.XX.XX.XX/var/.git/commondir'

I've hidden my server IP address with XX. This issue started suddenly, I had no problems or changes with my git if that is being implied by the error, first time I'm seeing this and I do not recall /var/.git/commondir being on the server (there are multiple git repositories in subfolders, but not in /var).  I tried reinstalling both nuclide client and server, problem persists. I have very little experience with Atom, any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading Atom to version 1.42